# How to insert text/path in beginning of URL Path

Tags: jquery, function, url, cookies

I am trying to figure out a way to add a certain word (in this case a city name) after the first backslash of a URL using jQuery.

The reason being is that I created a function where a cookie gets created with certain city information from when the user clicks on a certain location on a google map. I then use jQuery to get that city information from that cookie.

Below is an example of how I want it to function.

(i.e: https://linktowebsite.com/services/bumpers add the word "orange" in link -> https://linktowebsite.com/orange/services/bumpers)

This is how I am currently adding the city name to the URL. I realized that this only adds the city name to end of the URL but not after the first backslash after .com

```
jQuery('#menu-main-menu .menu-item a').each(function() {
  var nLink = jQuery(this);
  var locLink = Cookies.get('location');
   var _href = nLink.attr("href"); 
  nLink.attr("href", _href + locLink);
});
```

Here is the entire snippet!

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
    
    jQuery('.btnlocation').append('it worked');
    
    var CookieSet = Cookies.get('location');
    
    if (CookieSet == null){
 //no cookie
  console.log( 'No Cookies');
 return false;
} else {
 //have cookie
 var ThisLocation = Cookies.get('location');
   jQuery('#results').html('Welcome to Bumper Buddies ' + ThisLocation);
    
    jQuery('#menu-main-menu .menu-item a').each(function() {
  var nLink = jQuery(this);
  var locLink = Cookies.get('location');
   var _href = nLink.attr("href"); 
  nLink.attr("href", _href + locLink);
});
}



});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: it kind of did! it's very similar to the answers below! only difference is that i am using jQuery so i might need to rearrange a few things. Thank you for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some string manipulation using arrays should do the trick.

As per your example, "linktowebsite.com/services/bumpers" is the original link, and we're getting "orange" from the cookie.  Here's the code.  I added three lines:

```
jQuery('#menu-main-menu .menu-item a').each(function() {
  var nLink = jQuery(this);
  var locLink = Cookies.get('location');
  var _href = nLink.attr("href")

  var hrefArray = _href.split("/")   // 1
  hrefArray.splice(1, 0, locLink)    // 2
  
  var newHref = hrefArray.join("/")  // 3

  nLink.attr("href", newHref);
});
```

I numbered each of the added lines.  Let's go through them.

1. Here, we're using the `split` method to separate the _href string into an array using the forward slashes in _href.  `hrefArray` is now equal to:
   `["linktowebsite.com", "services", "bumpers"]`
2. `splice` is a convenient method.  You can [read more about it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) in the MDN docs.  In this case, I'm using it to insert `locLink` into index 1 in the array.
   Now, `hrefArray` should look like this: `["linktowebsite.com", "orange", "services", "bumpers"]`
3. Finally, we use the `join` method to connect all the elements of our array into a single string with each element separated by a separator of our choice.  In this case, we can just use "/" so that each element of the array is connected like so: `"linktowebsite.com/orange/services/bumpers"`

Comment: Woot! thank you for this @isaacsan! i had to change out the 2nd step (hrefArray.splice(1, 0, locLink)) to be (hrefArray.splice(3, 0, locLink)) and it worked perfectly!

Comment: Ah, I see.  Yeah, I just understood that the example link you provided was the actual link.  However, if the link would be different or if you would want to change where you'd be inserting the location into the link, you would have to change the number of the index you'd be inserting the location into.

Answer (score 1):

That is doable with plain JS using an array.

You need to split the `href` string with [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)... (creates an array)

Then create a new array with:

1. the first "splitted href" item using [shift](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift)
2. the city name coming from the cookie
3. the rest of the "splitted href" items

And join it all back to a string using [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

---

**EDIT**

I made you a function that takes the protocol (`http://` or `https://`) in account, if present.

```js
function insertCity(href, cookieValue){
  let protocol_match = href.match(/http(s)?:\/\//)
  let protocol = protocol_match ? protocol_match[0] : ""
  let href_splitted = href.replace(protocol,"").split("/")
  return protocol + [href_splitted.shift(), cookieValue, ...href_splitted].join("/")
}

// HTTP
let href1 = "http://linktowebsite.com/services/bumpers"

// HTTPS
let href2 = "https://linktowebsite.com/services/bumpers"

// No protocol?
let href3 = "linktowebsite.com/services/bumpers"

// Some cookie value
let cookie = "orange"

// Testing the function
console.log(insertCity(href1, cookie))
console.log(insertCity(href2, cookie))
console.log(insertCity(href3, cookie))
```

---

And that would be your use case:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
  jQuery(".btnlocation").append("it worked");

  var ThisLocation = Cookies.get("location");

  if (ThisLocation == null) {
    //no cookie
    console.log("No Cookies");
    return false;
  } else {
    //have cookie
    jQuery("#results").html("Welcome to Bumper Buddies " + ThisLocation);

    jQuery("#menu-main-menu .menu-item a").each(function () {
      var nLink = jQuery(this);
      nLink.attr("href", insertCity(nLink.attr("href"), ThisLocation));
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: So it kind of worked. Since this was in a jquery if/else statement i translated your js to jQuery. so when i tested it out i got this: http:/orange//linktowebsite.com/services

Comment: Maybe you have "orange/" from the cookie then...

Comment: Nope, just orange. I will probably be able to fine tune it if i looked at documentation you sent me. This is a great start! thank you!

Comment: Ho!!! That is because of the protocol `http://` lolll! Stupid me. Let me edit.

Comment: lol that was my issue with the above answer as well but I was able to read the documentation a bit to find out why.

Comment: Have a look now. ;)

Comment: Sweet thank you @louys I am definitely going to give this a try in a bit! i appreciate the lesson. Definitely expanded my knowledge on this!

Comment: I added your "revisited" use case with that function ;) Happy coding!